# Get Scroll position inside Element HTML not work in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get current Horizontal scroll position, however the result is always NaN.

This code its work when using `window` not `wrapper`

What should i do ?

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <span id="current view"> 0 </span>
   <div class="my-row m-0" id="lorem">
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_1">A</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_2">B</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_3">C</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_4">D</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_5">E</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_6">F</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_7">G</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_8">H</div>
  </div>
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
</div>
```

```
.my-row{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #34495e;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.my-row .item{
  width: 250px;
  height: 450px;
}

.my-row .item#data_1{
  background: var(--danger);
}

.my-row .item#data_2{
  background: salmon;
}

.my-row .item#data_3{
  background: royalblue;
}

.my-row .item#data_4{
  background: var(--primary);
}

.my-row .item#data_5{
  background: var(--info);
}

.my-row .item#data_6{
  background: greenyellow;
}

.my-row .item#data_7{
  background: limegreen;
}

.my-row .item#data_8{
  background: var(--success);
}
```

```
let wrapper = document.querySelector('#lorem');
let lastKnownScrollPosition = 0;

/* wrapper[0].scrollLeft = 0; */

wrapper.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  lastKnownScrollPosition = wrapper.scrollX;
    console.log(parseInt(lastKnownScrollPosition));
});
```

Here my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aditya_4420/v20sz43b/140/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**element.scrollTop** is what you need.

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('#lorem');
let lastKnownScrollPosition = 0;

wrapper.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  lastKnownScrollPosition = e.target.scrollTop; 
    console.log(parseInt(lastKnownScrollPosition));
});
```

```css
.my-row{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #34495e;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.my-row .item{
  width: 250px;
  height: 450px;
}

.my-row .item#data_1{
  background: var(--danger);
}

.my-row .item#data_2{
  background: salmon;
}

.my-row .item#data_3{
  background: royalblue;
}

.my-row .item#data_4{
  background: var(--primary);
}

.my-row .item#data_5{
  background: var(--info);
}

.my-row .item#data_6{
  background: greenyellow;
}

.my-row .item#data_7{
  background: limegreen;
}

.my-row .item#data_8{
  background: var(--success);
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <span id="current view"> 0 </span>
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
  <br class="mt-5 mb-5">.
   <div class="my-row m-0" id="lorem">
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_1">A</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_2">B</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_3">C</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_4">D</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_5">E</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_6">F</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_7">G</div>
     <div class="item col-8" id="data_8">H</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because, `window.ScrollX` would get the position for window's horizontal scroll position. In order to get wrapper's scroll position use `wrapper.scrollLeft` to get horizontal position, or `wrapper.scrollTop` to get vertical position.

```
let wrapper = document.querySelector('#lorem');
let lastKnownScrollPosition = 0;


wrapper.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  lastKnownScrollPosition = wrapper.scollLeft;
    console.log(parseInt(lastKnownScrollPosition));
});
```